# Average outputs of deep learning algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I'm trying to classify some audio clips, and to do so I have to split those audio clips that are each 30 seconds long, in to 1 second clips.
And then I want to put this 1 sec audio clips in a classifier and average the output of all 30 one-second audio files to have my final response. I want 1 output from every 30 inputs.

My problem is that I don't know how to feed them in my classifier, I can't use multiple imputs as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545316/average-layer-in-multi-input-deep-learning) because I have 30 of them and not only 2, it would be a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you are referred to is about having 2 separate input **pipelines** rather than 2 input audio clips. You would need to wrap your *30 one-second audio* data in a `Tensor` (if you are using Tensorflow, if not then use the equivalent of the framework you are using)

The `Tensor` can then be fed into your DeepLearning model's one input pipeline.

Checkout the tutorial for handling audio data in Tensoflow:
[Tensorflow Audio Data Preparation and Augmentation Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/audio)

Comment: Exactly, I don't need separate pipelines. I omminted many steps, obviously I did compute an FFT for every 1 sec clip. But at the end I have 30 arrays for every audio clip and I can't find anything that says how I should wrap them together in one tensor,  as you said.
Thanks for the reply!

Comment: In Tensorflow 2.x, Numpy and Tensor are interchangeable. This makes it easy to just wrap the 30 arrays in another Numpy array. You can refer [Tensors and operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics) for more on Tensor usage